# CryptoJS Encryption (AES)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cryptojs

my Code is written in Java, I want to use it into react-native, but I am not able to convert it properly in react native, I am stuck in it from last 36 hours.

I am able to encrypt the code , but the apis are written and I have to create a replica of android app.

```
input is : api/v1/master/Login/PinAuthentication

expected output is : BiR6DnP2PDlLRiRxlaqzK/p+ysGnvL6SF2SCZEN/UbIBQwJ/eDQT8uLuZffcT+kl
```

my react.js code is :

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let workingURL = "BiR6DnP2PDlLRiRxlaqzK%2Fp%2BysGnvL6SF2SCZEN%2FUbIBQwJ%2FeDQT8uLuZffcT%2Bkl"
let decryptedText = "BiR6DnP2PDlLRiRxlaqzK/p+ysGnvL6SF2SCZEN/UbIBQwJ/eDQT8uLuZffcT+kl"
let appstring = "api/v1/master/Login/PinAuthentication"
let appkey = "****************************************"

//JFACzfbeLzsha7vB5vl3QMgnl3iYX06LWb3tjjnNTYQkV8ZMFg+xEtxY/uM8vEZk
function encrypt10(){

  let ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appstring)
  let secSpec = [-53, -96, -53, -96, -53, -92, -52, -95, -54, -92, -54, -91, -54, -88, -54, -89]
  let ivSpec = [-53, -96, -53, -96, -53, -92, -52, -95, -54, -92, -54, -91, -54, -88, -54, -89]
  
  ivSpec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appkey)
  secSpec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appkey)

  console.log("ciphertext : " + ciphertext)
  console.log("secSpec : " + secSpec)
  console.log("ivSpec : " + ivSpec)

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(ciphertext, secSpec, {
    iv: ivSpec, //yes I used password as iv too. Dont mind.
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    keySize: 128 / 8,
});

console.log(encrypted.toString());

}
```

to test it I am using react-js because of crypto-js library.

```
private static byte[] getKeyBytes() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes = KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}

public static byte[] encrypt2(String value){
    try{
        byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec IVKey = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, IVKey);
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return outputBytes;
    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your most recent CryptoJS code and describe the problem.

Comment: hi @Topaco I have added code snippet of reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to me to be the derivation of the key.

The Java code performs a UTF8 encoding of `KEY` and then uses the first 16 bytes as key. In the CryptoJS code, you also perform a UTF8 encoding of `appkey` (with `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse()`), but then apply the *entire* data as key.

You need to shorten the data, e.g. with `secSpec.words.slice(0, 16/4))` and analogously for `ivSpec`, since you use the key as IV, which is insecure by the way.

With this change, encryption works with the CryptoJS code and the ciphertext matches the expected result / the result of the Java Code (for the true key):

```js
let appstring = "api/v1/master/Login/PinAuthentication";
let appkey = "****************************************";

function encrypt10(){

  let plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appstring);
  let secSpec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appkey);    
  let ivSpec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(appkey);

  secSpec = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(secSpec.words.slice(0, 16/4));
  ivSpec = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(ivSpec.words.slice(0, 16/4));

  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, secSpec, {iv: ivSpec});

  document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = encrypted.toString(); 
}

encrypt10();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="ct"></p>
```

Regarding the key: More robust than a UTF8 decoding is a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 or hex.

Comment: thank you very much .. can you please remove key from the code ?