# Getting Unique Salt for Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, password-encryption

Our requirement is to store each password with a unique salt.

Looking at their old code, I see it uses [RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetNonZeroBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getnonzerobytes).

The documentation says that it *"Fills an array of bytes with a cryptographically strong sequence of random nonzero values."*

That does not say that the salt is unique, though, does it.

Should I generate some data based on the time of day? Maybe a GUID? Or a combination of these?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This really belongs on [security.se]

Comment: @DanielA.White I have found that they don't really know much about coding in there

Comment: @jp2code: This question isn't truly about coding: it's about security. You're not asking how to create a GUID: you're asking whether you should create a GUID instead of using GetNonZeroBytes, e.g.

Comment: An appropriately sized (say 16+ bytes) salt generated with a cryptographic randomizer is extremely unlikely to repeat, and a few repeats are of no consequence from a security point of view.

Comment: When specs ask for a salt to be "unique" what they really mean is unguessable, and generated separately for each password. GUIDs are only unique because they're generated in a way that makes it _extremely unlikely_ to come up with the same value twice. A "cryptographically strong sequence of random" values meets the same criteria, as long as it's sufficiently long. GUIDs are both size-limited and more easily guessable than cryptographically strong random values, making them a worse choice for security purposes. Times of day are orders of magnitude worse, on both counts.

Comment: So, why is it that questions like these (https://stackoverflow.com/q/69537829/153923) are acceptable but mine are not? I've stopped using SO because all I get is negativity instead of help. I usually go elsewhere these days.

Comment: If you want to be certain of getting a unique salt, then use an encryption. Encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... with an appropriately sized block cipher.

Comment: @rossum, a simple example would be a great answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appropriate password-hash libraries usually generate the salt on their own, and include it directly into the hash-string, this is the recommended approach. A good example is BCrypt: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next/

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
string hashToStoreInDb = BCrypt.HashPassword(password);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
bool isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.Verify(password, existingHashFromDb);
```

If you need to generate the salt on your own, the usual way is to read random bytes from the random source of the OS as you did in your example, or as is shown in this example from the DotNet documentation [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-6.0).

The salt should be unique for each password, to prevent that a rainbow table can be used for more than one password. With a long random salt the chance is **extremely** small that you get the same salt twice. In the worst case, an attacker could use a rainbow table for two passwords instead of one, brute-forcing will still be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using suggestions from the comments, I will start with this:

```cs
public const int IV_SIZE = 32;

public static byte[] GetRandomSalt()
{
    var array = new byte[IV_SIZE];
    using (var crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(array);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: That should work, the odds of any repeats are infinitesimal.

Answer (score 1):

You want a 32 byte unique salt. For guaranteed uniqueness, rather than statistically highly probably uniqueness, you need a cipher. Because ciphers are one-to-one, if you encrypt unique inputs with the same key then you will get unique outputs. Hence encrypting a counter 0, 1, 2, 3, ... will give you unique outputs.

32 bytes is 256 bits. That is large for a block cipher, AES is 128 bits for example. You do not say how many unique salts you need. If you need less than 2^128 salts, then you only need to use one AES block, with 16 bytes of random added. Otherwise you will need two AES blocks. That requires extending the AES input to 256 bits with leading zeros and expecting a two block return from AES.

128 bit AES + random pseudocode:

```
global int counter  // 128 bit integer
global array key[]

generateUniqueSalt_v1()
{
  array saltPartOne[] <- AES.encrypt.ECB(counter, key)
  array saltPartTwo[] <- getRandomBytes(16)
  array salt[] <- saltPartOne concatenate saltPartTwo
  counter <- counter + 1
  return salt
}
```

256 bit AES pseudocode:

```
global int counter  // 256 bits if possible.
global array key[]

generateUniqueSalt_v2()
{
  array plaintext[] <- counter extended to 256 bits if needed
  array salt[] <- AES.encrypt.ECB(plaintext, key)
  counter <- counter + 1
  return salt
}
```

Comment: What language is this code in?

Comment: It is in [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode). You will need to convert it into your language of choice, presumably C#.

Comment: Password salts do not have the requirement to be guaranteed unique, a number from the random source of the OS is the usual way to go. The chance of a collision for a salt is absolutely negligible if a appropriate password-hash function is used which requires a long enough salt.